# How to create html table with subcolumns group?

Tags: html-table

I want to make a table in html that will be like this:

```html
<style>
BODY { color: black; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 80% }
TH { font-size: 80% }
TD { font-size: 80% }

TD.Layout { background-color: white}
TH.Title { background-color: #A0E0A0}
TD.Item { background-color: #E8E8E8}

</style>


<TABLE border ="1" cellspacing ="2" cellpadding ="6">
  <TR>
    <TH class="Title" rowspan = 2>Name</TH>
    <TH class="Title" align="center" colspan = 2>2017 statistics</TH>
    <TH class="Title" align="center" colspan = 2>2018 statistics</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TH class="Title" align="center">Value 1</TH>
    <TH class="Title" align="center">Value 2</TH>
    <TH class="Title" align="center">Value 1</TH>
    <TH class="Title" align="center">Value 2</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TH class="Title" align="center">John</TH>
    <TD class="Item" align="center">1</TD>
    <TD class="Item" align="center">2</TD>
    <TD class="Item" align="center">3</TD>
    <TD class="Item" align="center">4</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TH class="Title" align="center">George</TH>
    <TD class="Item" align="center">5</TD>
    <TD class="Item" align="center">6</TD>
    <TD class="Item" align="center">7</TD>
    <TD class="Item" align="center">8</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

The point is that in every year there will be 5 or 6 subcolumns and I want to group them somehow in order to be easier for somebody to look at the table and understand which subcolumn belongs to every year without looking the header every time. A nice solution could be different border color for every year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two easy solutions that I can think of are:

1. Styling based on year.

```html
<style>
BODY { color: black; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 80% }
TH { font-size: 80% }
TD { font-size: 80% }

TD.Layout { background-color: white}
TH.Title { background-color: #A0E0A0}
TD.Item { background-color: #E8E8E8}

.Year2017 {background-color: #145214}
.Year2018 {background-color: #000080}

</style>


<TABLE border ="1" cellspacing ="2" cellpadding ="6">
  <TR>
    <TH class="Title" rowspan = 2>Name</TH>
    <TH class="Year2017" align="center" colspan = 2>2017 statistics</TH>
    <TH class="Year2018" align="center" colspan = 2>2018 statistics</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TH class="Year2017" align="center">Value 1</TH>
    <TH class="Year2017" align="center">Value 2</TH>
    <TH class="Year2018" align="center">Value 1</TH>
    <TH class="Year2018" align="center">Value 2</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TH class="Title" align="center">John</TH>
    <TD class="Year2017" align="center">1</TD>
    <TD class="Year2017" align="center">2</TD>
    <TD class="Year2018" align="center">3</TD>
    <TD class="Year2018" align="center">4</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TH class="Title" align="center">George</TH>
    <TD class="Year2017" align="center">5</TD>
    <TD class="Year2017" align="center">6</TD>
    <TD class="Year2018" align="center">7</TD>
    <TD class="Year2018" align="center">8</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

2. CSS tooltip. Tooltip can represent the year and hence we don't need to look at header for year value.

For reference: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: This is it! It is just fine for me! Thanx a lot and happy new year my friend!!